# I don't use captcha in image upload form am I safe?

Tags: captcha

I don't use captcha for image upload form because I know that upload box value cannot fill automatically, needs to be filled by user manually. Are there any ways that somebody automatically post huge amount of image with some kind of script?

Comment: What makes you think that the box value can't fill automatically?

Comment: But also what viagra bots go around spamming upload forms? File uploads are usually exploited through malicious file uploads and an attacker would happily manually fill in a captcha to get a shell on your server, so you may be using captchas wrong

Comment: @wireghoul That depends on how the website works. Let's take for example an image hoster which list the most frequently uploaded images on their frontpage. Flooding it with advertisement might be a viable traffic generation method.

Answer (score 2):

This will not help you.

A user which uses a web browser has to fill it out manually. However, an attacker won't use a web browser. They will use a script which generates and sends HTTP-POST requests automatically. This will bypass any GUI-related complications and pass the file directly to your server.

To prevent this with a captcha, only accept a HTTP-POST with a file which also includes a valid captcha solution.

But a captcha isn't a surefire way to keep out spam either.

1. machine text recognition made great advances in the past years. Weaker captchas can be deciphered automatically.
2. There are sweatshops in developing countries where humans solve captchas around the clock in real-time for surprisingly low prices.
3. It is also not unheard of that attackes set up their own website with captchas. But they don't server their own captchas to their visitors, they serve your captchas so their visitors solve them and they can use their solutions to spam you.

Answer (score 0):

Captcha is commonly used to prevent automated bots from filling in HTTP forms with data.

If you don't have a captcha or any other security measures then ofcourse it can be automated to automatically fill in your image upload form.

This will prevent the basic bots but most advanced bot will be capable of bypassing such Captcha but here just implement this for now:
http://www.captcha.net/

You could do many other forms of filtering such as:

- IP blacklist
- IP can only sumbit x per y amount of time
  etc